# Will it be possible to use GTK3.2's HTML5 extension in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, gtk, html5

Does anybody know wether or not it willbe possible to use the GTK3.2's new HTML5-extension in Ubuntu 11.10? They announced that GNOME3.2 will be included, but will they build the GTK packages with the new HTML5-extension enabled?

Comment: That is a very interesting question. You do mean if you can run any standard GTK applications as a browserapp? Or if you can develop 3.2 apps that supports it?

Comment: Well, at first I would like to know, if I can run any GTK application as a browser application in the next Ubuntu release. But then I it would be interesting as well to know, how to develop those applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in Oneiric, it seems, but it should be possible in 12.04. Since this was only released a couple of days ago, it was probably too late to get it in 11.10. The GTK applications will just work. You'll run them like this: `GDK_BACKEND=broadway someapp`.